# HTML Select2 alignment with inline buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

I'm fairly new to web programming. I'm trying to make a simple Select2 picker and then have buttons next to it. The problem i'm having is I cant seem to figure out how to get the "Clear" and "All" buttons to Align evenly with the top of the select2 picker.

I say aligned with the top because as I add more selections to the multipicker, it will grow vertically. So I'm trying to make the buttons center aligned with the picker while there is nothing or just one thing selected. I'm using some Velocity template code in there too but I'm pretty sure thats all ok. All of the AUI classes used for formatting is from Atlassian Jira.  Here is a link to my

http://jsbin.com/lejixo/edit?html,output

JS Bin on jsbin.com

Any Suggestions??

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- External dependencies -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sinon.js/1.15.4/sinon.js"></script>
    <script src="//aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/6.0.0/js/aui.js"></script>
    <script src="//aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/6.0.0/js/aui-experimental.js"></script>
    <script src="//aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/6.0.0/js/aui-datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/6.0.0/css/aui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/6.0.0/css/aui-experimental.css" />
    <!-- / External dependencies -->
</head>
<body>
    <section id="content" role="main">
        <div class="aui-page-panel">
            <div class="aui-page-panel-inner">
                <section class="aui-page-panel-content">
                    <form id="admin" class="aui" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="aui-group">
                            <div class="aui-item">
                                <div class="field-group">
                                    <label for="baseline">Baseline(s):</label>
                                    <!-- Trigger -->
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        AJS.$(function() {
                                            var $exampleMulti = AJS.$("#baseline").auiSelect2({
                                                placeholder: "All"
                                            });
                                            AJS.$(".js-programmatic-multi-set-val").on("click", function() {
                                                $exampleMulti.val(["CA", "AL"]).trigger("change");
                                            });
                                            AJS.$(".js-programmatic-multi-clear").on("click", function() {
                                                $exampleMulti.val(null).trigger("change");
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                    <script>
                                        console.log($baselineD.class.name);
                                    </script>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <select id="baseline" name="baseline" style="width: 170px" value="${baseline}" multiple="">
                                            #foreach($baseline in $instance.getAllBaselines())
                                              <option value="${baseline}">$baseline</option>
                                            #end 
                                            #set ($listType = "java.util.ArrayList") 
                                            #if($baselineD.class.name == $listType) 
                                              #foreach( $bl in ${baselineD}) 
                                                #if(${bl})
                                                  <option selected="selected">${bl}</option>
                                                #end 
                                              #end 
                                            #else 
                                              #if ( $baselineD )
                                                <option selected="selected">${baselineD}</option>
                                              #end 
                                            #end
                                        </select>
                                        <div class="aui-buttons input-group-btn" role="group">
                                            <button type="button" class="aui-button js-programmatic-multi-set-val btn btn-default">
                                                All
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" class="aui-button js-programmatic-multi-clear btn btn-default">
                                                Clear
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field-group">
                                    <label for="priority">Priority:</label>
                                    <!-- Trigger -->
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        AJS.$(function() {
                                            AJS.$("#priority3").auiSelect2({
                                                placeholder: "All"
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                    <select id="priority3" name="priority" style="width: 170px" value="${priority}">
                                        #if(${priorityD})
                                          <option selected="selected">${priorityD}</option>
                                        #end
                                        ##<option value="All">All</option>
                                        #foreach( $priority in $instance.getPriorities())
                                          <option value="${priority}">$priority</option>
                                        #end
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS to this line and it will always stay centered to the right no matter if the height changed.

```
<div class="aui-buttons input-group-btn" role="group" style="margin-left:12px;position:absolute;top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">
```

You can add this to a class or keep it inline as I did. I did it this way so you can see where to place it.

Also you can change the `margin-left:12px;` to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks @kervon Ryan this worked as you explained. I modified the values a bit to keep it from centering on the select2 box as it grew. I just wanted it to anchor the top of the select2 area.